# Reserved error (-1524)

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007

I am upgrading some of my MS Access programs from 2003 to 2007 version. I have a variable stored "Public" in the main menu of a program. In another form, I write that variable to a record (the form is using unbound data). The VBA line "Rst![FieldName]=Forms![Main Menu].strUser" gives a RunTime error of 3000, Reserved error (-1524).

What the heck is going on???????

Thanks for any help given.

Comment: That seems an odd way to refer to a variable. Did it work in the 2003 version? Have you added a reference to DAO? Have you checked for corruption http://www.granite.ab.ca/access/corruption/symptoms.htm ?

Comment: It's exactly how you'd refer to a public variable in an open form. Not exactly common (or, in my opinion, advisable), butstill appropriate syntax.

Comment: What's your database? The non-Access error suggests to me that it's not a Jet/ACE data table, but likely an ODBC data source? Likely you should post the code where you open the recordset and make it editable. I suspect you're doing something incorrect in that step.

Comment: Any reason you can't just use a global variable in a plain code module instead of a form level public variable? It would make your life a whole lot easier. You might even consider using TempVars if you're trying to store a username or usercode and you'd like it to survive a code reset. This feature is available with 2007 and 2010.

Answer (score 1):

I encouteredthe error when updating an mdb split database (frontend backend) to Access 2010. The original mdb database used an internal linkage (an autoid number in one table linked to the same number defauted in a second table).  I encountered the problem when trying to import the first table mentioned above.  I could not import the table or copy-paste the table without getting the "Reserved error (-1624) error.

The solution was to import the other tables that imported ok without the problem into a new 2010 database, and then use a make table query to duplicate the problem table in the new 2010 version.  The process preserved the auto id numbering, so the internal relationship is preserved in the new, updated database.

Answer (score 0):

I did have the same problem and after look the records in one table discover that one record had language changed and was all in Chinese alphabet. 
After delete the record no more error.

Looks like, in my case, the error was generated because the primary key was used to link to another table. I did a check after and manage to identify one record in the other table that do not exist in the main table (record I deleted).